# Cleaning piston ring grooves

Tags: piston-ring

My piston ring grooves had quite a bit of (oily?) gunk settlement. Is it appropriate to clean them with a dental pick? Is there risk to scratching them? My assumption is not since it is not a gasket mating surface. Also, what chemical is best to clean it with, WD-40, brake cleaner or something like acetone, mineral spirits or alcohol?

Also -- should I lube the grooves (with regular engine oil or assembly lube) when installing the rings (to facilitate moving to the right position)?

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested to you previously, **use the old piston rings**. They are the *exact* width you need to clean the ring lands. Just break off about 1/3 of a ring. Besides that, use some cleaning solvent like brake/carb cleaner. Even WD40 will work just fine.

You don't need to oil the groves. Just the outside of the piston when you go to install them.

Comment: I needed something more pointy than old rings to scrape the hardened settlement

Comment: @amphibient - No, you really don't. This is the way most EVERYONE cleans piston ring grooves/lands. There is a tool, but this works perfectly at zero cost. Try it and you'll see what I mean.